# Undefined Value??[cvFindContours] [Contour]

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-c++, opencv, undefined

I am using VS C++ 2010 professional and SP1.

**My code :**

```
    CvSeq* firstContour = NULL;
    int n = cvFindContours(grnt1, g_storage, &firstContour, sizeof(CvContour), CV_RETR_CCOMP, CV_CHAIN_APPROX_NONE, cvPoint(0,0));
```

**I get this error after run :**
        **An unhandled exception of type 'System.Runtime.InteropServices.SEHEcxeption' Occurred in Project.exe
        Addtional information:External component has thrown an exception**

**And My problem  :** 
Autos is showing me that : **Contour value is undefined value .** 
But I dont understant beacuse I defined it. İf ı remove cvFindContours line dont give me undefined value. But ı want to use cvFindContours

Help me please :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem solved :)

1-) Your image shoulde be one channel image

For Example : IplImage *grnt1= cvCreateImage(cvGetSize(grnt1),8,1);

That's ALL :D